# how to add some space for a specific DIR with a USB key

Tags: usb-drive, disk-usage, user-space

I have a /home/Completed dir.
For some reasons, I can not move this directory. Now my system is quite full.
So, I would like to grant some space to the /home/Completed directory from a usb key.
Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can't move it due to operational reasons (in other words, you can move, but things won't work anymore), then here's what you a gotta do:

In Terminal:

```
cd /home
mkdir usb
sudo mount /dev/sd_
sudo mv /home/Completed/* usb/
sudo rm -r /home/Completed
sudo umount /dev/sd_
sudo mv usb Completed
sudo mount /dev/sd_ Completed
```

And the USB drive will hold the contents, but they will show up as that same directory.  Also make sure to run

```
sudo mount /dev/sd_ /home/Completed
```

when you boot up, otherwise it won't show up.

REPLACE /dev/sd_ with /dev/sdc or /dev/sdd or whatever your USB shows up as in /dev/.

If you can't move it due to permissions, then you're out of luck.  Use the USB for storing other stuff you can move.